# Difference between two dates to return 1 or 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I return 1 or 0 using COUNT between two dates?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckCharterDate]
@DateCheck date,
@DateCheck2 date,
@charterID int
AS
SELECT Count(StartDate)
FROM Booking    
WHERE StartDate >= @DateCheck
AND EndDate <= @DateCheck2
AND CharterID = @charterID
RETURN 0
```

This stored procedure only returns 1 or 0 whenever the user selects exactly the two dates that are in the database but if they select a date in between, it returns a 0 and it says that it's available.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: *it returns a 0 and it says that it's available* - please explain that sentence. How are `0` and `available` related? What is `it`?

Comment: @jarlh it's Visual Studio ASP.NET

Comment: @MrDarkness96 no, it's not. jarlh asked you about your *database management system* (dbms), not coding environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Case...when` when you want user defined output

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckCharterDate]
@DateCheck date,
@DateCheck2 date,
@charterID int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN Count(StartDate)=0 THEN 0
ELSE 1 END AS Count_StartDate
FROM Booking    
WHERE StartDate <= @DateCheck2 
  AND EndDate >= @DateCheck
  AND CharterID = @charterID
END;
```

**Why I Changed the order of inequalities?**

Since for overlapping date ranges what is the basic condition:
If you have to check `start_date` and `end_date` is overlapping between `@DateCheck` and `@DateCheck2` `( @DateCheck < @DateCheck2)` then

Check

if `start_date` is less than `@DateCheck2` or not And also `end_date` is greater than `@DateCheck` or not.
So that's why there should be a change in the inequalities.

Comment: I'm still (badly) surprised users with 2k+ rep still post answers with no explanation... Why did you change the order of inequalities? I still don't fully understand OP's question, although it seems clear a `case` is needed.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't answer my question as to why you changed the order of inequalities in the `where` clause. Also you are using `@DateCheck2` twice and not `@DateCheck`, so I'm still puzzled to why OP marked *your* answer. (not saying it is bad, but I think it could be improved)

Comment: Sorry That was typing mistake

Comment: Why are you always skipping the part where I ask you why you changed the order of inequalities in your `where` clause?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake... I edited my answer with explaination

Comment: Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for overlapping date ranges.
The way to test if two ranges overlap is to make sure one starts before the second ends, while the second starts before the first end. You can see a visualization of this in the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckCharterDate]
    @DateCheck date,
    @DateCheck2 date,
    @charterID int
AS
    SELECT Count(StartDate)
    FROM Booking    
    WHERE StartDate <= @DateCheck2
    AND EndDate >= @DateCheck
    AND CharterID = @charterID
```

Also, as Gordon Linoff noted in his answer, you should use `exists` instead of `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `COUNT()` for this.  From a performance perspective, it is suboptimal.

Instead, use `EXISTS`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckCharterDate] (
    @DateCheck date,
    @DateCheck2 date,
    @charterID int
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM Booking b
                              WHERE b.StartDate <= @DateCheck2 AND
                                    b.EndDate >= @DateCheck2 AND
                                    b.CharterID = @charterID
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) as overlap_flag
END;
```

I don't recommend that you return a value from a stored procedure -- unless that value is a status.  Instead, just write a user defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_CheckCharterDate (
    @DateCheck date,
    @DateCheck2 date,
    @charterID int
) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @flag int;
    SELECT @flat = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                      FROM Booking b
                                      WHERE b.StartDate <= @DateCheck2 AND
                                            b.EndDate >= @DateCheck2 AND
                                            b.CharterID = @charterID
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0
                    END) as overlap_flag;
    RETURN @flag;
END;
```

The function can simply be used as any other function.  For instance:

```
WHERE dbo.udf_CheckCharterDate( . . . ) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckCharterDate]
        @DateCheck date,
        @DateCheck2 date,
        @charterID int
    AS
    declare @count int

        set @count = SELECT Count(StartDate)
        FROM Booking    
        WHERE StartDate <= @DateCheck2
        AND EndDate >= @DateCheck
        AND CharterID = @charterID

if (@count > 0)
   begin
      select 1
   end
else
   begin
      select 0
   end
```